# Symbol's function defintion is void: org-show-all

Tags: org-mode, debugging

I get the above error when trying to archive my org agenda using `C-c C-x C-a` and/or `C-c C-x C-s`, according to instructions over [here](https://orgmode.org/manual/Archiving.html#Archiving). My archive location is set the default.

---

## UPDATE:

After following @Tobias' instruction below, I get this error when using `TAB` on my headings to fold them:

```
org-cycle-internal-local: Symbol’s function definition is void: org-flag-region [7 times]
```

---

I just installed the newest version. Now I have two separate `org.el`:

```
./.emacs.d/elpa/org-20190701/org.el
./.emacs.d/elpa/org-20190624/org.el
```

But the flag region issue still persists.

I think Emacs seem to be confused over which `init.el` to read as well, because all my settings are left unevaluated after a restart.

Can't seem to locate the system `org.el` (if it exists).

---

## Follow-up QUESTION

A natural follow-up question would be: How to prevent such confused situation when updating `org` to the newer version?

Comment: In the `org-mode` repository that I cloned with the following command-line as of today (06/29/2019) `git clone https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode.git`, I grepped for the regex `org-show-all`.  I see that the function `org-show-all` is defined in the file `org.el` beginning at line 6115 -- the line number will vary depending upon the version of `org-mode` and the date the `org.el` file was modified by the developers.  Therefore, you might want to try `(require 'org)` so that the file gets loaded before doing whatever it is that you want to do ...

Comment: Same error came up after evaluating the code. Do I have to restart the buffer?

Comment: An error indicating that the symbol's function definition is void usually means that the file containing the function definition has not yet been loaded.  To be of further assistance, it would be helpful to know what version of `org-mode` you are using -- perhaps you have a stock version that shipped with Emacs and you installed a newer version of `org-mode` and your installation is confused ...  If you have the `*.el` files you can grep them, or there is a grep option for certain versions of grep that can scan `gz`-ipped files -- search for `defun org-show-all` to see where it is defined ...

Comment: What does `M-x org-version` show? I guess you have `mixed installation` in your version string. I think the version you installed fights the built-in version and the built in `org.el` does not yet have `org-show-all`. You can test that with `M-x load-library org`. Since `org-agenda.el` has been loaded from the new repro `org.el` should also be loaded from the new repro on explicit call of `load-library`. If you are not sure which `org.el` is found by Emacs you can also call `M-x locate-library org`.

Comment: Org mode version 9.1.9 (release_9.1.9-65-g5e4542 @ ~/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20190624/)

Comment: Library is file ~/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20190624/org.elc

Comment: What does `C-h f org-show-all` say now? Still undefined? You updated your question. Now you speak about `org-flag-region`. Is the original issue gone now?

Comment: `org-show-all` is still undefined. So is `org-flag-region`. But I am at least able to `TAB` the headings after a restart, possibly with `org-flag-heading` and `org-flag-subtree`.

Comment: Seeing the same thing now. `Org mode version 9.1.9 (release_9.1.9-65-g5e4542 @ /Users/gmauer/.emacs.d/elpa/develop/org-plus-contrib-20200511/)`

Comment: Restarting emacs seems to have fixed it